# line number is different in notepad vs. excel

Tags: excel, numbers, line, notepad++

When I browse a file in Excel 2007, I see the last line number is 5154 but when I browse the same file from notepad++, I see the last line number is 5156.  I can't figure out why the line number is different in excel and notepad++. Do you know what could be the reason?

Comment: What type of file are you looking at? If it's a CSV or other type of deleimited plain-text format then it's possible one or more values contain a line-break.

Comment: Excel and notepad++ are two different programs that can have different definitions of line breaks

Comment: I am looking at a list of book titles (text file) and confused because excel is showing 5154 while notepad++ is showing 5156.  If these two programs have different definitions of line breaks, I wonder which count is correct.

Comment: That depends on your definition of correct.

Comment: I would suggest checking a couple areas that could be causing issues.  The first is at the top of the file.  See what row number the first data line is in.  The header could be split over a couple lines or there could be blank lines above it.  Make sure there are no blank lines at the end that are being counted.  You could also copy the text from notepad into excel and compare it side by side with whats there.

Comment: I figured out by comparing one line (excel) by one line (notepad++).  In conclusion, there were two rows in excel showed as single line (row) but had extra spaces which caused them to take up 2 lines when pasted them in notepad++.